# Vast ads implementation

Tags: vast

i am using vast to show ads on my videos using plyr. I need a way to implement these vast ads.
`ads: { enabled: true, tagUrl: 'https://servedbyadbutler.com/vast.spark?setID=31158&ID=184908&pid=164800' }`

This is my code which inserts vast ads into the videos. Whenever i use the xml link from another ad server, it works but when i copy the xml into my site and use link it doesn't.

I tried entering the xml code into my site and tried to serve the ads directly from my site but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

When I go to your VAST URL:

https://servedbyadbutler.com/vast.spark?setID=31158&ID=184908&pid=164800

...I see that you have reached your trial ad request limit.

[image: adbutler trial request limit reached]

That's probably the reason. If you're looking for a VAST video ad server alternative to AdButler, you can consider [VASTify.io](https://www.vastify.io).